# How do i stop continuous builds in CCNET dashboard?

Tags: build, triggers, cruisecontrol.net, dashboard, continuous

I have successfully setup a CCNet web dashboard and everything is working fine has expected. 
And i have triggered a force build from CCNET and it ran successfully with out causing any error. but, the problem what i am facing is that, whenever i'm triggering the build from CCNET dashboard (Force) it's keeps on to build continuously again and again.

Actually it should stop the build automatically right after the success of the latest build.

can any one help me out, how to stop the continuous builds ????

Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, check your triggers.

See "Next Build Time" column on the dashboard. If it has date/time then project has a trigger. If not - you'll see "Force Build Only".

Answer (score 0):

Check your build's triggers.  You've probably got it set to force a build at a very frequent interval.